# Transitions for clicking and displaying content

Tags: reactjs, transition, semantic-ui-react

So, I've been trying to figure out some stuff with react and semantic-react-ui, I am new to react, so pardon the "oh you're doing it wrongs".

Below are key components to my code, what I am trying to do, is when a user clicks on an item in the list, the related content to that list item will display to the right within the card. If the same element is clicked, it will default to the default description for the specific card.

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {keys} from 'lodash';
import {Card, Container, Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import ChoreDetails from './ChoreDetails';

class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderChores = chores => (
        chores.map(chore => this.renderChore(chore))
    );

    renderChore = chore => {
        return (
            <Card key={chore.name}>
                <Card.Content>
                    <Card.Header>
                        {chore.name}
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Card.Meta>
                        {chore.assigned}
                    </Card.Meta>
                    <ChoreDetails chore={chore}/>
                </Card.Content>
                <Card.Content extra>
                    <a>
                        <Icon name='tasks' />
                        { keys(chore.choreList).length } Chores
                    </a>
                </Card.Content>
            </Card>
        )
    };

    render() {
        const displayChores = this.renderChores(this.props.chores);

        return (
            <Container>
                <Card.Group doubling={true} stackable={true} itemsPerRow="2">
                    { displayChores }
                </Card.Group>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default HomePage;
```

**ChoreDetails.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Card, Container, Grid, List, Transition} from 'semantic-ui-react';

class ChoreDetails extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            visible: true,
            animation: 'drop',
            defaultDescription: this.showDescription(props.chore, 'drop'),
            itemClicked: null,
            itemActive: null,
        };
    }

    renderChoreList = list => (
        list.map(item => <List.Item as="a" key={item.name} onClick={this.showDetails.bind(null, item)} item={this.props.item}>
            <List.Icon name="tasks" />
            <List.Content key={item.name} content={item.name} />
        </List.Item>
    ));

    showDescription = (item, animation) => {
        return (
            <Transition
                transitionOnMount={true}
                key={'default_description_' + item.name}
                reactKey={'default_description_' + item.name}
                visible={true}
                animation={animation}
                duration={300}
            >
                <Container>{item.description}</Container>
            </Transition>
        )
    };

    showDetails = (item) => {
        this.setState({
            itemClicked: item,
        });
    };

    getDescriptions = (choreGroup, itemClicked, animation) => (
        choreGroup.choreList.map((chore, index) => <Transition
            key={choreGroup.name + '_' + index}
            reactKey={choreGroup.name + '_' + index}
            visible={(itemClicked.name === chore.name)}
            animation={animation}
            duration={300}
        >
            <Container>{chore.description}</Container>
        </Transition>)
    );

    render() {
        const { itemClicked, defaultDescription, animation } = this.state;
        const displayChoreList = this.renderChoreList(this.props.chore.choreList);
        const descriptionContainers = (itemClicked) ? this.getDescriptions(this.props.chore, itemClicked, animation) : defaultDescription;

        if (itemClicked) {
            console.log(descriptionContainers);
        }

        return (
            <Card.Description>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column width={4}>
                            <List>
                                {displayChoreList}
                            </List>
                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column width={12}>
                            <Transition.Group>
                            {descriptionContainers}
                            </Transition.Group>
                        </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid.Row>
                </Grid>
            </Card.Description>
        )
    }

}

ChoreDetails.defaultProps = {
    chore: []
};

export default ChoreDetails;
```

How can I get the proper order of elements to show, when clicked, so that the current active element fades, and then on completion of its transition, it triggers the incoming items transition in?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: edited to add the question that I left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "lift your state up" to the `HomePage` component. Right now, each `ChoreDetail` component has its own state, but the `ChoreDetail` component should have a shared state that is held by `HomePage`. Then, you can pass `this.state.activeItem` down, like `<ChoreDetails activeItem={this.state.activeItem} />`. If you don't share the state between the mappable component, they will each be keeping track of their own state, which is not what you want.

Also, it isn't necessary to pass `this.props.items` to any function, because it's already in scope for all of the methods. You can just use `this.props.items` directly in your `renderChores` method.

Edit (update after seeing question added):
I don't know enough about semantic-react-ui to answer the question about fading. You have some React issues, so solving those *may* fix your transition issue, but I can't be sure.